# Read 2 numbers and skip 2 numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file which has lines like this:

`206,8,157,8,118,8,205,8,151,8,160,8,126,8,244,8,139,8,166,8,164,8,154,8,177,8,118,8,161,8,180,8,201,8,156,8`

I want to read initial 2 numbers, skip the next 2 numbers, read the next 2 numbers and so on into an array. Since the text file is huge and Matlab is not able to hold all data in memory, I read one line at a time. The text file might have some other text content as well, which I ignore using regexp. My incomplete code is as follows:

```
fileID = fopen('4.dat'); %Open file
line= fgets(fileID); %read first line
testArray=[]; %Temporary array which will be appended to main array
I=[]; %Main array

while ischar(line)
    fromX = regexp(line,'(\d*\,\d*\,){2,}','match'); %Find 2 consecutive numbers delimited by ","
    fromXMat = cell2mat(fromX); %Convert to matrix
    fromXMatNum = str2num(fromXMat); %Convert to numbers from string
    testArray = fromXMatNum(1:2:numel(fromXMatNum)); %Read every 2nd number
    I = [I,testArray]; %Append to main array 
end
```

I have also tried textscan, but did not get the desired result. I want the below output:

```
Input: 206,8,157,8,118,8,205,8,151,8,160,8,126,8,244,8,139,8,166,8,164,8,154,8,177,8,118,8,161,8,180,8,201,8,156,8,
Output: 206,8,118,8,151,8,126,8,139,8,164,8,177,8,161,8,201,8
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the text file might have some other content as well". Does it  mean whole lines may be discarded or that there may be non-numeric text within a line that also contains numbers?

In any case if the variable `line` is a string of comma separated integers, you can get them into an array and extract alternate pairs of elements with `sscanf`, the modulus operator and logical indexing:

```
numbers = sscanf(line, '%d,');
output = numbers(mod(0:length(numbers)-1, 4) < 2);
```